# For Point-to-point distance matrix ?(about 10 000 points, as a result 10000 * 10000 rows ) how to save use Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate the distance matrix between 10,000 points.

1. how to save the results with mysql. (The result is 10000 * 10000 lines), how to design the data table is more reasonable? If the table is divided, how is the design more reasonable?
2. I need to randomly query the distance matrix between some points (eg: 2000), how to query more efficient.

store table:
[image]

store_store_diatance  table:
[image]

eg: now, store_store_diatance table had about 100000 * 100000 rows , The query efficiency is very bad. So how to improve, whether it is mysql or java code. thanks!

sql:

```
SELECT *
from store_store_distance
where origin_id in ('','','',...about 1000 points) 
and target in    ('','','',...about 1000 points)
```

but,it was very bad

result:
[image]

Comment: What does Java have to do with this question?

Comment: Cant you just have t tables - points and distance?

Comment: Maybe scale down your problem to just 10 points.  Show us sample data, along with the exact output you want/need.

Comment: *The result is 10000 * 10000 lines* not true as the distance from X to Y is the same as from Y to X thus can be ommited.

Comment: thank you，I just updated the description.

Comment: And what is the query ? Run EXPLAIN your query to see why it is slow (probably no indexes)

Comment: X to Y not equals Y to X , because the Road single line.

Comment: Why do you want to save these? Calculate the distance when someone gives you an X and a Y

Comment: Why do you want to save these? Calculate the distance when someone gives you an X and a Y .  =======>  Because I need to line according to the distance matrix.（driving route）

Comment: What queries do you need to answer with this database? Are approximate answers ok?

Comment: What queries do you need to answer with this database？ ========> Optimize query efficiency. Or design a more reasonable table structure

Comment: First try `WHERE origin_id in(SELECT id FROM store WHERE ...)`. And then post `EXPLAIN PLAN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE STORE`

Comment: That query is about to return 1000^2 results. Dont expect for it to be fast.

Comment: The fastest way I can think of is to put everyting in memory and fetch from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
table point{
     id
     location
     ..whatever more
  }

table distance{
    id
    point1 //FK to point id
    point2 //FK to point id
    distance
    ..whatever more
}
```

to get distance between points

```
SELECT distance FROM distance where (point1=x and point2=y) OR (point1=y and point2=x)
```

and thats assuming you are not duplicating distances as distance from X to Y is the same as from Y to X.

Comment: but ,I have to query the distance matrix of about 1000 points at a time. so , this sql had bad efficiency.